# c++: override template member function in parent class

Tags: c++, function, templates, virtual-functions

Let's suppose I have such a structure of classes: base class `Object`, which is a parent class for `Bool`, `Int`, `Float`, `Bytes` and `Unicode` classes. Before I had some functions like `Bool cast_bool() const`, `Int cast_int() const`, etc. as virtual functions in the `Object` class and in all child classes I've implemented these functions separately.

It seems that a better solution is to implement `template <typename TYPE> TYPE cast() const` function instead. However, since C++ prohibits virtual template functions I don't know how can I complete this task. What I need is to provide `template <typename TYPE> TYPE cast() const` for `Object` and its childs. Generic `Object::cast<TYPE>() const` will just throw `CastError`; then for every type like `Bool`, `Int`, etc. I'll implement functions like `Bool::cast<Bool>() const`, `Int::cast<Bool>() const`, etc. I'm even planning to add cast to builtin objects, though now I just overload `operator bool() const`, `operator signed short() const`, etc. If there is no implementation, template must switch to its generic form from `Object` class, just throwing an error. Is there a way to do it (perhaps I need to use some pattern)? Or it is easier to leave functions like `Int cast_int() const`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your cast from data is stored in the base class, there is no reason why you can't add a templated member function to the same base class. Then have child classes call that. Or maybe I'm missunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 4):

Add an intermediate class like in the example below or just use `dynamic_cast` without any template methods.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class> class ObjectImpl;

class Object
{
public:
    virtual ~Object() {}

    template <class T>
    T cast() const
    {
        if (auto obj = dynamic_cast<const ObjectImpl<T>*>(this))
        {
            return obj->cast();
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::string("cast error");
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
class ObjectImpl : public Object
{
public:
    virtual T cast() const = 0;
};

class Bool : public ObjectImpl<bool>
{
public:
    bool cast() const override { return true; }
};
class Float : public ObjectImpl<float>
{
public:
    float cast() const  override { return 12.34f; }
};

int main()
{
    Object* obj = new Float;

    cout << obj->cast<float>() << endl;

    try
    {
        cout << obj->cast<bool>() << endl;
    }
    catch (std::string e)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing doesn't sound like a very good idea, C++ is not Java or C#... nevertheless you could do it like this:

```
class Object
{
public:

     template<typename T>
     T& cast()
     {
          return cast_impl(std::declval<T>());
     }

private:
     virtual bool& cast_impl(bool&){ throw std::bad_cast(); }
     virtual int& cast_impl(int&){ throw std::bad_cast(); }
};

class Boolean : public Object
{
    bool value_;
public:

private:
     bool& cast_impl(bool) override
     { 
         return value_;
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a set of flags

```
enum Castablity{
    intable    = 0x1,
    floatable  = 0x2,
    doubleable = 0x4,
    bytable    = 0x8,
    stringable = 0x10,
    unicodable = 0x20,
};
```

and keep a `virtual int castable() const` function in each of these class, e.g. your `Int::castable()` will return `intable | floatable | doublable | stringable` . and YOu need to have another templated map that takes an Castablity enum value and return target type in typedef .

```
template <typename T>
struct type_value;

template <enum v>
struct value_type;

template <>
struct type_value<Int>{
    enum {value = intable;}
};
template <>
struct value_type<intable>{
    typedef Int data_type;
};
```

and a global cast function

```
template <typename T, typename U>
U cast(const T& original){
    if(!original.castable(type_value<U>::value))
        //throw exception
    return detail::cast<U>(original.internal_data());
}
```

You can have a virtual method that takes an integer value instead of taking types at compile time. or you can have an internal structure to store all types of object values. something like `boost::any`

and you can write another specialization in detail namespace that will convert that internal type to target type

```
namespace detail{
  template <typename T>
  /// you may have specialization for different types
  struct casting_helper{
    static T cast(const internal_type& data){

    }
  }
  template <typename T>
  T cast(const internal_data& data){
      return casting_helper<T>::cast(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you are fine with runtime casts.

```
class Object
{
public:

     template<typename T>
     T& cast()
     {
          return *dynamic_cast<T*>(get());
     }

private:
     virtual void* get() = 0;
};

class Boolean : public Object
{
    bool value_;
public:

private:
    void* get() override
    {
        return &value_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type wrapper for the object.

```
struct TypeWrapperBase
{
protected:
    static int m_counter;
};

int TypeWrapperBase::m_counter = 0;

template<typename T>
struct TypeWrapper:
    TypeWrapperBase
{
    static int m_type;
protected:
    static int AllocateType()
    {
        m_counter++;
        return m
    }
public:
    static int GetType()
    {
        return m_type;
    }   
};

template<typename T>
int TypeWrapper<T>::m_type = TypeWrapperBase::m_counter++;

void main()
{
    std::cout << TypeWrapper<int>::GetType() << std::endl;   // prints 0
    std::cout << TypeWrapper<float>::GetType() << std::endl;  // prints 1
    std::cout << TypeWrapper<bool>::GetType() << std::endl; // prints 2
}
```

Now this way you can simulate an any object by comparing  el1.GetType() with el2.GetType(). If it's equal you can perform a static cast